# SQL server how to apply restriction for each different sets and put the value as a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I really don't know how to explain my issue in one sentence so basically what I want to do is

Say we have table

```
ID | Type     | Date     | Paid 
 1 | Initiate | 20160101 18:21:50.270 |  0.00  
 1 | Create   | 20160101 18:22:50.270 |  2.00  
 1 | Add      | 20160101 18:23:50.270| 40.00  
 1 | Add      | 20160101 18:24:50.270| 80.00  
 2 | Initiate | 20160101 18:31:50.270|  0.00  
 2 | Create   | 20160101 18:32:50.270|  2.00  
 2 | Add      | 20160101 18:33:50.270| 30.00  
 2 | Add      | 20160103 18:33:50.270| 90.00
```

I want a query that select DISTINCT ID's

```
1
2
```

---

I also want a column called FirstPaid where if when when the row for each card that the type 'ADD' appears first(As in the most recent date) then the value of that paid column will be used. For example, In ID 1, the first time type 'Add' appears is in third row, so the value of paid column on that row would be use. All in all, it would look like this.

```
1 | 40.00 
2 | 30.00
```

---

Also, if possible, I want to create another column called Recharge, where the next time type 'ADD' appears once more, that value will be used. If the next type add appears the next day like ID 2, then that value for Recharge will be used.

```
1 | 40.00 | 80.00 
2 | 30.00 | 90.00
```

- I'd really appreciate help in anyform, I been messing around with the query for hours. I am using TSQL, Thank you so much

Comment: Do you mean to get the lowest Paid (out of all ADDs) along with your ID?

Comment: In id 1 how can you tell 40 is first and 80 second?, it's the same id and date, there's no way to guarantee the order of the rows

Comment: The most recent ADD, sorry, the Date was actually a datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[Type] varchar(50),Date DateTime,Paid money)
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 1,'Initiate','20160101 18:21:50.270', 0.00),
( 1,'Create'  ,'20160101 18:22:50.270', 2.00),  
( 1,'Add'     ,'20160101 18:23:50.270',40.00),  
( 1,'Add'     ,'20160101 18:24:50.270',80.00),  
( 2,'Initiate','20160101 18:31:50.270', 0.00),  
( 2,'Create'  ,'20160101 18:32:50.270', 2.00),  
( 2,'Add'     ,'20160101 18:33:50.270',30.00),  
( 2,'Add'     ,'20160103 18:33:50.270',90.00)

Select ID
      ,Col1 = sum(case when RowNr=1 then Paid else 0 end)
      ,Col2 = sum(case when RowNr=2 then Paid else 0 end)
From (
        Select *,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by Date) 
         From   @YourTable
         Where [Type]='Add'
     ) A
 Group By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  Col1    Col2
1   40.00   80.00
2   30.00   90.00
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
     select id, paid, 
(select sum(paid) from t t2 where t2.id=t1.id and t2.date<>mindate and t2.type='Add') recharge 
     from
     (
     select *, min(date) over(partition by id) mindate
     from t where [type]='Add'
     ) t1
     where mindate=date
```

I'm summing the recharges in case there is more than one for the same id

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but it could give you an idea to solve your problem.

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Paid, T3.Paid
FROM TAB T
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, TYPE, MIN(DATE) DATE
                FROM TAB
                WHERE TYPE = 'Add'
            ) AS T2
        ON T.ID = T2.ID
            AND T.TYPE = T2.TYPE
            AND T.DATE = T2.DATE
    INNER JOIN TAB T3
        ON T3.ID = T2.ID
            AND T3.TYPE = T2.TYPE
            AND T.DATE > T2.DATE
WHERE T.TYPE = 'Add'
```

The important thing is that you should first find the first record for you ID, TYPE, which is done in the subquer. From that, you could present any information related.